# Motion on Pi Zero W low frame rate

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, motion-detection

I am using a RSPI Zero W to record videos using motion detection. I have read others doing this easily with frame rates of 5 per second and above. I am only trying to get 2 frames per second. 
Everything works fine, except the videos recorded do not keep up with real time. I still get 2 frames per second, but many of the frames are duplicates.
It seems that the PI0W can not keep up with it, but the CPU usage never gets much higher than 50%. Using a Class 10 SD card so I do not think it is a disk I/O problem.

I originally did this on a PI2B with no problems in 720p. I tried reducing the resolution to 640x480 and get the same result.
Any suggestions?

---

Setup:

- Raspberry Pi Zero W
- Raspbian 9.4 stretch
- Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
- PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1
- Samba Version 4.5.12-Debian
- Motion 4.0 (installed via apt-get)

---

```
motion.conf
```

https://pastebin.com/Mr438ned

[Example Video: Watch the timestamp. It should be updating every second](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u7R-nmdeWTr55bsXGaH4f_d6wyVT69IW/view?usp=sharing)